# calling function return error: extra argument in call

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a sequence of animations where on button tap a circle's alpha becomes 0,3 and a counter animates the same circle in a brighter color

the animation function is:

```
func animateElement(duration: CFTimeInterval, element: CAShapeLayer, key: String ) {
    let animatinon = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animatinon.duration = duration
    animatinon.fromValue = 0
    animatinon.toValue = 1
    animatinon.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    element.add(animatinon, forKey: key)
```

and the call in buttonTapped (UIbutton):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 0.3}) {(true) in
        self.animateElement(duration: 10, element: self.shapeLayer, key: "animateCounter") {(true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 1
            })
        }
}
```

the error is on self.animateElement- ( Extra argument 'key' in call)

after research I found that if I enclose the animateElement in an if statement like so:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 0.3}) {(true) in
        if 1 == 1 {
            self.animateElement(duration: 10, element: self.shapeLayer, key: "animateCounter")
        }
         {(true) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 1
            })
        }
}
```

the error on animateElement will disappear but I have 2 new errors- 
1. closure expression is unused on the true in line after the function
2. '()' is not convertible to 'Float'- on the line where I change the opacity back to 1 on circleShapeLayer

any help is much appreciated

Comment: You're trying to pass a closure to your `animateElement` method, but it does not take one as a parameter. The error message is horribly misleading, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `completion` handler to your `animateElement` method and call that closure when the `CABasicAnimation` finishes:

```
func animateElement(duration: CFTimeInterval, element: CAShapeLayer, key: String, completion: @escaping ()->() ) {
    CATransaction.begin()

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
    element.add(animation, forKey: key)

    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    CATransaction.commit()
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 0.3 }) { _ in
    self.animateElement(duration: 10, element: self.shapeLayer, key: "animateCounter") {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the errors are now gone but the animation doesn't happen one after the other- I may have neglected to mention that I would like each animation to execute once the former animation completed. right now they are all happening at once.

Comment: It is actually the last animation that has to be executed after animateElement finishes. - right now    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.circleShapeLayer.opacity = 1 is happening at the same time